# Malware-free DVD Maker

Tags: windows, gratis, optical-media

I'm looking for a **free** DVD maker program that works on Windows 10, but I can't find any "official" programs from a trusted brand, which makes me paranoid about viruses. Does anybody know of a known safe DVD maker?

Comment: What is a *DVD maker*? Do you want to burn just data DVDs, or videos? Do you want to *author* your videos, i.e. combine fragments, edit menus, etc? Please [edit] your question.

Comment: And asking for malware-free is a bit strange. *No one* publishes software saying "Look, has malware!". Maybe you mean to ask ""without adware", "without [PUP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potentially_unwanted_program)s"?

Comment: @jan I mean a program that burns video files onto DVDs. I know no programs tell you they contain malware, but for example Windows Movie Maker definitely has no malware because that would destroy their brand. I'm looking for a trusted brand that has nothing to gain by giving you a virus.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer? If so, could you either please accept one of the answers here, or post your own answer, in order to help others who read this in future? Thanks.

Comment: You're not coming back, are you? You haven't logged in since the day that you posted this

Answer (score 3):

There's [DVDStyler](http://www.dvdstyler.org/en/) which can be used to author and burn DVD discs. It's distributed under GNU GPL license.

Answer (score 2):

beside [**DVDStyler**](http://www.dvdstyler.org) i can also recommend [**Bombono DVD**](http://www.bombono.org/), both of them are GUIs for [DVDAuthor](http://dvdauthor.sourceforge.net/).

---

some features of DVDStyler:

- user-friendly interface with support of drag & drop
- import of image file for background
- flexible menu creation on the basis of scalable vector graphic
- change the font/color and other parameters of buttons and graphic objects
- place buttons, text, images and other graphic objects anywhere on the menu screen
- create and burn DVD video with interactive menus
- design your own DVD menu or select one from the list of ready to use menu templates
- customize navigation using DVD scripting
- add multiple subtitle and audio tracks
- support of AVI, MOV, MP4, MPEG, OGG, WMV and other file formats
- support of MPEG-2, MPEG-4, DivX, Xvid, MP2, MP3, AC-3 and other audio
  and video formats
- use MPEG and VOB files without reencoding
- support of multi-core processor

---

some features of Bombono DVD:

- Comfortable Drag-n-Drop support
- Motion menus
- Real WYSIWYG Menu Editor with live thumbnails
- Subtitles support
- Excellent video viewer: Timeline and Monitor
- Transcoding, if necessary (from AVI/MKV/MOV/MPEG4...)
- You can author to folder, make ISO-image or burn directly to DVD
- Reauthoring: you can import video from DVD discs

Answer (score 0):

Not gratis but [Nero](https://www.nero.com/eng/?vlang=gb) has been a very well known and respected brand of DVD Authoring & Burning software. If obtained from the official site you should be good to go and you can also sometimes find magazine cover discs with a copy of a slightly dated version.

Comment: I don't think Nero is free to use.

Comment: Missed the second "free" I'll add the gratis tag.